# Как узнать какой процесс использует FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

Используя FileSystemWatcher я подписываюсь на изменение всех файлов .txt в заданной директории

```
public static void Run(string pathDir)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = pathDir;          
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);            
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }


    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Engine engine =  new Engine();
        engine.DoWork(e.FullPath);
    }
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как я могу из другого процесса, запущенного со всеми необходимыми правами под рутом определить какой процесс отслеживает нужную мне директори. Другими словами как узнать какой процесс использует функцию FileSystemWatcher и какие директории мониторит?

Comment: Можно повесить hook на winapi фунции связанные с FileSystemWatch, для этого правда придется внедрять свой код с другие процессы и патчить таблицу экспортируемых функций.

Comment: А какое у этого могло бы быть валидное применение?

Comment: @VladD Не понял, что именно вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @PrimusSingularis Хотелось бы более подробно, начиная от "внедрения своего кода и патчей таблицы экспортируемых функций"!

Comment: https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/160-apihooks

Comment: @PrimusSingularis Не понимаю какое отношение, ваша ссылка имеет к вопросу?

Comment: @VladD Я так все таки и не понимаю что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @YuryBakharev: Ну, я не могу себе представить применение того, что вы хотите, не для деструктивных действий. Отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: @VladD На самом деле из за недостатка в опыте, хотел разобраться в итоге с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734708/223583 , там мне ответили.